# XSD for validation using assertions

Tags: xml, xsd

Just wondering whether it is possible to use XSD for validation of an atttribute against other elements / attributes. An example as follows:

```
<foods>
<food type="meat">
    <name>Chicken</name>
</food>
<food type="meat">
    <name>Beef</name>
</food>
<food type="meat">
    <name>Pork</name>
</food>
<food type="fruit">
    <name>Banana</name>
</food>
<food type="fruit">
    <name>Apple</name>
</food>
<food type="vegetable">
    <name>Carrot</name>
</food>
<recon vegetable="1" fruit="2" meat="3"/>
```

Is it possible to define an XSD that can validate both the type of the recon attributes, but also the value therein? For example the following XPath identifies that there are three "food" elements of "type" = "meat"

```
count(/foods/food[@type='meat'])
```

I was investigaing the use of an assertion as follows

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:element name="food" type="foodType"/>
<xs:complexType name="foodType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="meat"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="vegetable"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="fruit"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="foods">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="food" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="recon"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="recon" type="reconType"/>
<xs:complexType name="reconType">
    <xs:attribute name="fruits">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
                <xs:assertion test="count(/foods/food[@type='fruit']=.)"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="vegetables">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
                <xs:assertion test="count(/foods/food[@vegetable])=."/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="meats">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
                <xs:assertion test="count(/food/foods[@type='meat'])=."/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

</xs:schema>

However, I am getting an error in XML Spy. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See following : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_facets.asp

Comment: What kind of error did you get ? Did you try to follow the [xsd assertions documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) ?

Comment: It would help if you told us what error you are getting. For example, it might indicate that you are not using an XSD 1.1 processor, in which case xs:assertion is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Assertions only have access to the subtree rooted at the element you are validating, that is, the element on which the assertion is defined; and the assertion uses XPath expressions that are relative to that element. In your case I would expect the `foods` element to have the assertion

```
test="count(food[@type='fruit']) eq recon/@fruits"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:element name="food" type="foodType"/>
<xs:complexType name="foodType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="meat"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="vegetable"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="fruit"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="foods">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="food" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="recon"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="count(food[@type='fruit']) eq recon/@fruits"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="recon" type="reconType"/>
<xs:complexType name="reconType">
    <xs:attribute name="fruits" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="vegetables" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:attribute name="meats" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Model the other two conditions after the shown `<xs:assert test="count(food[@type='fruit']) eq recon/@fruits"/>`.

And in the instance the attribute names need to match the schema e.g. `<recon vegetables="1" fruits="2" meats="3"/>`.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought assertions validated against a subtree that doesn't include a document node, so a leading "/" shouldn't work?

Comment: @MichaelKay, admittedly I only tested against the Python XmlSchema validator, perhaps I should have more carefully checked against other validators.

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelKay, I have rechecked and you are right, the XPath down from `/` was wrong; still the type where I put the `xs:assert` instead of an `xs:assertion` was right; and I have of course corrected the XPath now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Martin Honnen and  @Michael Kay. Figured out that the assertion needs to be at the foods complex type. Complete working XSD as follows:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
<xs:element name="food" type="foodType"/>
<xs:complexType name="foodType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="type">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:enumeration value="meat"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="vegetable"/>
                <xs:enumeration value="fruit"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="foods">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="food" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="recon"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:assert test="(count(food[@type='fruit'])=recon/@fruits) and (count(food[@type='meat'])=recon/@meats) and (count(food[@type='vegetable'])=recon/@vegetables)"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="recon" type="reconType"/>
<xs:complexType name="reconType">
    <xs:attribute name="fruits">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="vegetables">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="meats">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short">
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="foods">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:short"/>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:assert test="@foods = @vegetables + @meats + @fruits"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

</xs:schema>